TOC issue where the TOC has chapter before the Bibliography Heading
Hello I would like to remove the word Chapter before my Biblio heading as shown below:

Before I was having issues where the Bibliography was not showing up at all.  Now it does but has a chapter in front.
This is where I am at:
\clearpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\bibliography{Reference/mybib}

Everything Appears correctly in the document except the TOC entry.  Any help would be appreciated.

Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us help you and add a minimal working example (MWE) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with \documentclass{...} and ending with \end{document}. Currently it is unclear, why you get the CHAPTER in the ToC. Maybe it is because of the class you are using or because of a preamble definition. But as we don't know it we cannot reproduce it.

this is not the default behaviour, I don't think. so presumably you've changed the default somewhere ... or some package or you class has changed it.

% Template file for a standard thesis
\documentclass[11pt]{isuthesis}
%\usepackage{chapterbib}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % This changes fonts to type 1 fonts the default in this package is type 3
% Standard, old-style thesis
\usepackage{isutraditional}
%\usepackage{indentfirst}

not sure how to make this appear as code

@MatthewGervasi You can make it appear as code by editing your question instead of posting it as comment. please make sure that we can actually compile the code you show by making a small, but compilable test document.
